# Trouble identifying colors for Intellisense tool tips and mouseovers in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, color-scheme

I've installed the color theme customization plug-in for Visual Studio 2013, and am having difficulty identifying and changing the background and foreground colors for Intellisense areas displayed on mouse-over events.

A screen shot is below showing the two areas that I'm struggling with.  The top shows the helper dialog which appears when I delete and re-add the opening parentheses next at the line showing "@Html.PropertyFor(".  Either I need to adjust the foreground color for the very light grey text, or change the background to something darker than the off white.

[image]

The second picture shows a typical Intellisense box.  But the contrast on that is too low, so I need to either make the foreground text lighter, or the background box lighter.

After searching in the theme editor for quite some time, I'm unable to isolate these settings.  I also inspected several settings under Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors, but was unable to identify these specific foreground/background combinations in the intellisense tool tips.  I need assistance fixing both of these areas.  Thanks for your help.

=== Edit 12/2/2014 at 4:33 PM ===

I found part of the solution.  To make the text lighter, select Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors. Then toggle the Show Settings For list to "Editor Tooltip".  You can change the "Plain Text" foreground color.  But the background color cannot be edited.  So I changed the foreground to white.  This helped with case 2 shown above.

But with case 1, where there is a highlighted line for the available method overloads, that text still has a white background.  I still need a solution for that.  How can I make that white background dark?  Thanks.

=== Edit 7/24/2015 8:00 AM Central ===

Joe, thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I have Productivity Power Tools installed. After turning "Colorized Parameter Help" off, the hint shown in the first graphic above went completely white.  Probably that's because I have the foreground color set to White (ala Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors).  Here is an example.

[image]

So I turned "Colorized Parameter Help" back on, and this is what it looks like for me right now.

[image]

This is at least legible, though the colorization is gone.  I still don't know how to make that white background dark in that specific dialog.  Since I can at least read the text with the workaround, this is a low priority item.  What I imagine is that the ability to tweak that setting just doesn't exist within the color theme customization plug-in.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/31574915/492

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the Productivity Power Tools add-in installed?  If so, either remove it or set Colorized Parameter Help to off under Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools.