# How can I change Intellisense tooltip colors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

How can I change the colors of the tooltip shown by Intellisense under Visual Studio?

I've customized my editor colors to get white text on a dark background, by keeping VS theme to "Blue" (I find that the Dark theme lacks contrast), but now the Intellisense tooltip is unreadable.

[image: unreadable tooltip]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The quickest and easiest fix is to change the following colors:

- *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *Fonts and Colors* → *Show settings for* "Environment":

  - ToolTip
  - ToolTip Border
- *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *Fonts and Colors* → *Show settings for* "Editor Tooltip":

  - Plain Text

[image: options]
[image: options 2]

Here I managed to make the tooltip readable with my dark editor colors on a "Blue" theme:

[image: tooltip]

---

If that's not enough, you could install the [Color Theme Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor) addon as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597899/825024).

Comment: In VS 2017 I had to re-open the current document to see the effect on the tooltip, or to open a new document to see it.

Comment: @40detectives Thank you so much!  I had to do the same in VS 2019.

Comment: @KristenHammack it may be worth to note that the issue of having to restart the IDE or reopen the files to see the tooltip correctly happened to me **LOTS** of times, even without me changing the theme colors for a while. So every now and then VS decides to use the terrible gray background and I had to close and restart or reopen. Hope that is not a problem in VS2019 :sigh:

Comment: @40detectives I have never encounter such a situation in VS2019. Though not in VS2017 either...

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: The tooltips for code completion items still show the old background - any idea what items to change to set the tooltip background?