# Visual Studio showing white text on overloads of methods in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Hi all I was trying a different theme today in visual studio while coding in C# called `NightOwl` and for some reason for all other themes I tried whenever I use a method in C# and it shows the overloads, they are written in white background in which I cannot read what the overload actually does. Here is a screenshot to explain what I am talking about.

[Click here for snapshot of my problem.](https://gyazo.com/092e162fe6a6b13542c4c7a443449dce)

Is there a way to fix this? Or is it the theme's issue, I tried with other themes and was getting same issue.

Comment: How did you setup themes? Where did you choose "NightOwl"?

Comment: Extensions, typed theme and downloaded NightOwl then went to tools and choose from general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the quickest and easiest fix is to change the following colors:

Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors → Show settings for "Environment":ToolTip
[image]

Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors → Show settings for "Editor Tooltip": Plain Text
[image]
Result picture:
[image]

If that's not enough, you could install the [Color Theme Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor) addon as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574915/overriding-intellisense-colors-in-visual-studio-2015/31597899#31597899).